# Need help about php framework (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know php well. But I am a very new learner of php framework . I am learning codeigniter 2.0.3. I am trying  to develop a simple hello world application.

I have tried this code..

```
class Hello extends Controller{
  function Hello(){
    parent::Controller();
  }
  function you(){
    $this->load->view("you_view");
  }

}
```

But unfortunately I am receiving this error  ...

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\hello_world.php on line 7

Comment: its `CI_Controller` not `Controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
            /* use this only for setting default values, 
            loading helpers, models, ... */
    }
    function you() {
      $this->load->view("you_view");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

`Controller` should be `CI_Controller`, like this:

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller{
```

Answer (score 1):

CI_Controller not Controller on

`class Hello extends Controller{`

becomes

`class Hello extends CI_Controller{`

Comment: So choose the best answer and give a guy his rep!

Comment: i would like to second that emotion @eysikal :)

Answer (score 1):

Here more information , examples and user Guide. [Check this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Change `Controller` to `CI_Controller` in your code