# Selecting just one row from a joined MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a social networking site in PHP/MySQL. I am currently developing status update and comments on status's system. I am trying to show all status of mine and comments on certain status. For doing that I have two tables: `comment` and `user_status`.

I have used this MySQL query,

```
      SELECT * FROM user_status LEFT JOIN 
      comment ON id_status = comment.status_id
      WHERE sender_id = '$id2'
      OR receive_id = '$id2'

     /* $id2 is my id */
```

I have successfully showed status and one comment. But the problem is, when the number of comments are more than one, then the status shows more than one times. How much same status will be showed depends on how much comments available on certain status. But I would like to be able to display same status only one time, and display more than one comments (if available) on certain status.

Comment: @Mushfiqul. If you're just interested in the status table columns, then try modifying your query thus: `SELECT DISTINCT user_status.* ...`.

Comment: (Also, please accept the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9946565/472495) - someone has linked to instructions on how to do that for you.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much a PHP problem as it is confusion about how SQL joins work.

It sounds as if what you really want is not so much a join but a distinct set of records from two tables.  Until your SQL skils develop a little more, consider simplifying things by making two queries -- one each for comment and user_status.  Also consider requesting just the specific fields you're interested rather than using `SELECT *`.

[Here is a visual explanation of different SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), in case you want to pursue this with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not displaying the raw results from the query, but rather are piping them to an html page to display.  Display only the most recent status in a textbox.  then display thin a table or list an ordered list of the comments.

Your query is correct.

Comment: My php code below....


`$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_status LEFT JOIN 
      comment ON id_status = comment.status_id
      WHERE sender_id = '$id2'
      OR receive_id = '$id2'");

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $r['status'];
echo "<br/>".$r['comment'];
}

`